# XSLT transformation in mozila is treating <!DOCTYPE> tag as plain text and getting displayed on web page

Tags: html, xml, xslt, cross-browser

While doing `XSLT` `transformation` at browser end Mozilla is treating `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">` as plain text and putting it on webpage as first line, whereas IE is displaying the output correctly

Below is the xml and xsl to reproduce this issue

File Name - testdoctype.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="testxdoctype.xsl"?>
<MainHeader>
<ReportType Label="report type">Test</ReportType>
</MainHeader>
```

File Name - testdoctype.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
<![CDATA[
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
]]>
</xsl:text>

  <div id="body">
   <h1>REPORTS : <xsl:value-of select="./MainHeader/ReportType"/></h1>
  </div>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Attached output images from IE and Mozila [image]

[image]

Any Help to resolve this issue apart from server-side XSLT transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use XSLT as designed with an `xsl:output` directive defining any `doctype-public` and/or `doctype-system` you want. The XSLT processor in Mozilla browsers does not support disable-output-escaping as it does not serialize the transformation result, instead it renders the result tree. See the FAQ https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XSL_Transformations_in_Mozilla_FAQ#Can_I_do_disable-output-escaping.3F.